# How do I remove the ask.com toolbar?

Tags: uninstall, toolbar

I'm wondering how can I remove this annoying toolbar in IE and Firefox.
I already uninstalled it, rebooted my PC but it still shows it in my browser.

If I click on "Add Remove/Programs" I can still see it and if I click remove it says:

> The path: "C\Docume~1\MyName~1\Locals~1\Temp{30BCD5D3-6B83-4BB0-97A5-8D98DA79B261}Ask Toolbar.msi cannot be found. Verify that you have access to this location and try again or try to find the installation package Ask Toolbar.msi in a folder from which you can install the product Ask Toolbar"

I tried to find it but it says that no files were found.

I'm wondering how can I get rid of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find it impossible to remove it in a normal way, here is what to do.

1. Open IE and go to Tools>Manage Add Ons, in the new window at the top pane find the ask tool bar, highlight it and then click "more information" in the lower pane, another window will open, carefully copy down the "Class ID" {including the brackets} in a notepad txt file so you can copy paste it in the next step. Be very careful to copy the exact string, make no mistakes when doing this.
2. Now open regedit, do a edit>find, copy that string {including brackets} into the search box, only tick the "look at" "keys" box, then tick "match whole string only" box, hit find next, it will find the first key that matches that string, when it does hit the delete button and confirm deletion, then hit find next again, keep doing this and delete all keys that match that string, should not be that many 3~4.

Ask tool bar will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall it from [ask.com](http://sp.ask.com/toolbar/install/web/ask/download.php) and then remove it. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem before I got a software named

- [Yamisoft Windows 7 Manager (for Windows 7)](http://www.yamicsoft.com/windows7manager/index.html)
- [Yamisoft Vista Manager (for Windows Vista)](http://www.yamicsoft.com/vistamanager/index.html)
- [Yamisoft WinXP Manager (for Windows XP)](http://www.yamicsoft.com/xpmanager/index.html)

It has a tool named "Smart Uninstaller" which will uninstall damaged installs completely.