# Can I forbid apps called "something toolbar" from installing?

Tags: windows-7, windows, toolbar

My dad has a windows 7 PC, and everytime I check the "Ask toolbar" or some other browser toolbar is there. I don't know which software update includes it, can I forbid application called "*toolbar" from installing, or at least to have windows ask for a password ?

Comment: "I don't know which software update " very likely java.

Comment: which is weird, because I first heard about it when a site using java did not work as long as that toolbar was installed

Comment: This is a brilliant idea, although I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This can't be done.  Would be easier to just not allow your father to install applications himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the admin rights from your dad, turn it just a plain user.

then remove the toolbar, check the registry and filesystem to seen if it really gone. check this for help removing it:

[How do I remove the ask.com toolbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/173546/how-do-i-remove-the-ask-com-toolbar?rq=1)

if it show up again, its something you already have installed (probably some malware that is cashing for each toolbar installed).

If its installed just on your dad profile, its something he is doing/visiting that installs that (probably via a security problem in a browser, java, acrobat reader, flash, etc, etc)

if doesn't show up again... problem solved :)

Comment: Just to add - the Java installer/updater includes the Ask toolbar, which is a likely culprit.